# I want to change the video source of a html5 Video with js

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, video

I want to change the source of the video with a click on a different video thumbnail on a site. I don't want to leave the site and go to a different one with each video, I want to stay on one site and be able to watch all videos there. I was trying it like that (with bootstrap):

```
<video id="mainvideo" width="640" height="360" controls>
    <source id="vidsrc" src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<div onclick="mainVideoFrame()" class="clip-wrap">
    <a class="clip">
        <div class="poster-image">
            <img onclick="mainVideoFrame()" class="lazy" src="assets/img/transparent.gif" data-original="assets/videos/thumb.jpg">
        </div>
        <span onclick="mainVideoFrame()" class="clip-title">Title here</span>
        <i class="icon-large"></i>
        <span class="client">...</span>
        <span class="clearfix"></span>
    </a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function mainVideoFrame() {
        document.getElementById("vidsrc").src = "assets/videos/video.mp4";
    }
</script>
```

I hope someone here got a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

pass in the class  with the onclick span onclick="mainVideoFrame(this.className).then in the function take it in mainVideoFrame(videoid) then use that the decide which video to show